# C# using one method on timer-based and UI event-based calling

Tags: c#, .net

In WPF app I have a timer which cyclically performs some database quering operations (LINQ to SQL) and visual controls updating operations by calling a particular method.

Sometimes I need to call this the same method by UI events (button clicks, for example).

Is there any danger, in case timer-based calling and UI event-based calling of this the same method take place simultaneiously? Or .NET framework protects me from a danger like this?

Is using one method in a way like this totally OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what does the method do, exactly? If it updates the UI, you'll need to make sure you marshall back to the UI thread (using a `Dispatcher`) for that part.

Does the method touch any shared state? If so, again you'll need to be careful.

Basically there's nothing inherently unsafe about a single method being called from two threads simultaneously... but equally there's nothing to automatically protect you from doing unsafe things (in terms of concurrency) within that method.

Comment: Thanks Jon! Please, help me to understand, If I use DispatcherTimer and its dispatcherTimer.Tick event handler, does it mean that everything done from this "dispatcherTimer.Tick event handler" is done on different (new) thread?

Comment: It doesn't.  You're fine, that timer can only Tick when the UI thread is idle.  No locking is required.

Answer (score 0):

The timer and click event would be running on different threads and could execute the method at the same time.  It may be worth putting a synclock around any critical section within the method. i.e. if the code calculates a value and etc.

Comment: Locks shouldn't be introduced in a "just in case" fashion. Calculating a value is absolutely fine - if it doesn't touch shared state.